# Surjections from genus $n$ surface group to free group of rank $n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces, free-groups

Let $\Sigma_n$ be a genus $n$ surface, let $\mathcal{H}_n$ be a genus $n$ handle body, and let $F_n$ be a free group of rank $n$.  Fix an identification of $\pi_1(\mathcal{H}_n)$ with $F_n$.    I know several proofs of the following result:

**Theorem**: Let $\phi\colon \pi_1(\Sigma_n) \rightarrow F_n$ be a surjection.  Then there exists an orientation-preserving homeomorphism $\psi\colon \Sigma_n \rightarrow \partial \mathcal{H}_n$ such that $\phi$ factors as
$$\pi_1(\Sigma_n) \stackrel{\psi_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow} \pi_1(\partial \mathcal{H}_n) \longrightarrow \pi_1(\mathcal{H}_n) = F_n.$$

However, I do not know any references for it, nor who to attribute it to.  Does anyone know any references, preferably the original one?

Comment: It might be due to Zieschang.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: That's one of the people I thought might have proven it, but I haven't been able to find it in his papers.  On the other hand, he wrote so much and a lot of it is in long book-length lecture notes that I could very well be missing something.

Comment: Did you check his book 'Surfaces and Planar Discontinuous Groups'?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: My vague memory is that book is mostly devoted to things like finite subgroups of the mapping class group, but it's been a while since I opened it.  I'll have to wait until tomorrow to get it from our library (since it seems we don't subscribe to whatever I would need to download it for free).  Do you think this might be in there?

Comment: Bestvina and Feighn call it a folk theorem, and mention Zieschang and Stallings. https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0467v2

Comment: The Zieschang paper they cite is: Alternierende Produkte in freien Gruppen. *Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg*, 27:13–31, 1964.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first formal proof is due to Zieschang, Stallings probably knew it:

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=187195&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=101&mx-pid=161901

There is a discussion at the end of the paper that refers to a correspondence with Lyndon. There it is mentioned that the claim is implicit in Satz 2.

Answer (score 4):

I think this result can be found in ``Heegard splittings and splitting homomorphisms",by W.Jaco, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 144 (1969),365--379.